# What is a word for doing something that you don't want to do?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

I am reading Of Mice and Men, and I am trying to come up with a word that describes

> how George manages to shoot Lennie at the end of the book.

I have come up with *Self Discipline*, and *Overcoming Weakness*, but none of those really seem to suffice.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: **moral conflict**?

Comment: Offhand, [trudged](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trudge) through.

Comment: @user3306356, I like that! Want to put that in an answer so I can +1 it and accept it? Thanks for the input by the way @SrJoven!

Comment: Reluctantly - word for doing something that you don't want to do.

Comment: The metaphorical string 'bite/biting the bullet' is perhaps the most usual way to put this, but is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider: **moral conflict** or **ethical dilemma**

> An ethical dilemma is a complex situation that often involves an apparent mental conflict between moral imperatives, in which to obey one would result in transgressing another. *[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_dilemma)*